# Using AccessToken of OAuth 2.0 in GData API

Tags: google-oauth

Is it a valid practice to associate the AccessToken retrieved from Google Client API (Service Account)
and use it in GData API ?

The reason is that Google Client API uses OAuth 2.0 and GData API uses the older version of OAuth 1.0.
So will it work ?

Comment: Which api exactly are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

The GData API can also use OAuth2. See the revelant doc for two very common GData APIs :

- [Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index?hl=fr#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20)
- [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=fr#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20)